# Como salvar e alterar dados no banco utilizando checkstate de uma checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Boa tarde,

Preciso salvar as informações com condição, pois na hora de cadastrar o patrimônio fiz uma checkbox que representa se o patrimônio é interno ou externo.
Se está checado é externo e se não está checado é interno. 
Com isso se está checado eu libero somente os ComboBoxes das informações externas e se não está checado eu libero somente os ComboBoxes das as informações internas. Gostaria que as informações fossem salvas diante dessas condições contidas no código abaixo.

Obs: a parte de salvar está funcionando, porém as informações se perdem ao editá-las, pois uso a mesma tela para editar as informações.

```
using Patronum.Negocio;
using Patronum.Negocio.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Patronum.Grafico
{
    public partial class ManterPatrimonio : Form
{
    public Patrimonio PatrimonioSelecionado { get; set; }

    Patrimonio patrimonio = new Patrimonio();

    public ManterPatrimonio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ManterPatrimonio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregaExterno();
        CarregarComboBoxes();
    }

    private void CarregarComboBoxes()
    {
        {
            cbSetores.DisplayMember = "DescricaoSetor";
            cbSetores.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbSetores.DataSource = Program.Gerenciador.TodosOsSetores();

            cbGestores.DisplayMember = "DescricaoGestor";
            cbGestores.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbGestores.DataSource = Program.Gerenciador.TodosOsSetores();

            cbFornecedores.DisplayMember = "DescricaoFornecedor";
            cbFornecedores.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbFornecedores.DataSource = Program.Gerenciador.TodosOsFornecedores();

            cbEmpresa.DisplayMember = "DescricaoEmpresa";
            cbEmpresa.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbEmpresa.DataSource = Program.Gerenciador.TodosOsClientes();

            cbSetorEmpresa.DisplayMember = "DescricaoSetorEmpresa";
            cbSetorEmpresa.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbSetorEmpresa.DataSource = Program.Gerenciador.TodosOsClientes();

            cbResp.DisplayMember = "DescricaoResp";
            cbResp.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbResp.DataSource = Program.Gerenciador.TodosOsClientes();
        }
    }

    private void btSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Patrimonio patrimonio = new Patrimonio();

        if (Int64.TryParse(tbId.Text, out long value))
        {
            patrimonio.Id = value;
        }
        else
        {
            patrimonio.Id = -1;
        }

        if (ckbExterno.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            patrimonio.SetorCliente = cbSetorEmpresa.Text;
            patrimonio.RespCliente = cbResp.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            patrimonio.Setor = cbSetores.Text;
            patrimonio.Gestor = cbGestores.Text;
        }

        patrimonio.Nome = tbNome.Text;
        patrimonio.NomeCliente = cbEmpresa.Text;
        patrimonio.Nfe = tbNfe.Text;
        patrimonio.Fornecedor = cbFornecedores.Text;
        patrimonio.ServiceTag = tbServiceTag.Text;
        patrimonio.DataAquisi = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpDataAquisi.Text);
        patrimonio.PrazoGarant = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpPrazoGarant.Text);
        patrimonio.Obs = tbObs.Text;
        patrimonio.Ativo = ckbAtivo.Checked;

        Validacao validacao;
        if (PatrimonioSelecionado == null)
        {
            validacao = Program.Gerenciador.CadastrarPatrimonio(patrimonio);
        }
        else
        {
            validacao = Program.Gerenciador.AlterarPatrimonio(patrimonio);
        }

        if (!validacao.Valido)
        {
            String mensagemValidacao = "";
            foreach (var chave in validacao.Mensagens.Keys)
            {
                String msg = validacao.Mensagens[chave];
                mensagemValidacao += msg;
                mensagemValidacao += Environment.NewLine;

            }
            MessageBox.Show(mensagemValidacao);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Patrimônio salvo com sucesso!");

        }
    }

    private void btCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ManterPatrimonio_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(PatrimonioSelecionado != null)
        {
            this.tbId.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.Id.ToString();
            this.tbNome.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.Nome;
            this.cbSetores.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.Setor;
            this.cbGestores.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.Gestor;
            this.cbSetorEmpresa.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.SetorCliente;
            this.cbEmpresa.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.NomeCliente;
            this.cbResp.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.RespCliente;
            this.cbFornecedores.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.Fornecedor;
            this.tbNfe.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.Nfe;
            this.tbServiceTag.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.ServiceTag;
            this.dtpDataAquisi.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.DataAquisi.ToShortDateString();
            this.dtpPrazoGarant.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.PrazoGarant.ToShortDateString();
            this.tbObs.Text = PatrimonioSelecionado.Obs;
            this.ckbAtivo.Checked = PatrimonioSelecionado.Ativo;
        }
    }

    private void ckbExterno_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregaExterno();
    }

    private void CarregaExterno()
    {
        if (ckbExterno.CheckState == CheckState.Indeterminate)
        {
            cbSetorEmpresa.Enabled = true;
            cbResp.Enabled = true;
            cbSetores.Enabled = true;
            cbGestores.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (ckbExterno.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            cbSetorEmpresa.Enabled = true;
            cbResp.Enabled = true;
            cbSetores.Enabled = false;
            cbGestores.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cbSetorEmpresa.Enabled = false;
            cbResp.Enabled = false;
            cbSetores.Enabled = true;
            cbGestores.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: você tem que verificar a propriedade `Checked`: `if (ckbExterno.Checked) { ... }`

Comment: Mas aí se encaixa em um if e else, 2 if, if else if ? Já tentei das 3 formas, porém sempre quando vou editar as informações ele não salva corretamente